# Creating dynamic range for VBA Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Currently I am making user form on Excel VBA and using combobox.
I have range(A2:A61) named "Division" in which was included divisions of company.
When I add this data into combo row source, I put named range - Division.
But on the other hand divisions are dynamic, I mean new divisions are created during the year.

The problem is when I created new division I can see its name on Cell A62 but it doesn't include range - named division. As the result I can't see updated combobox list.

Firstly I tried to choose range as (A:A) and called it division. In this case I can see updated combobox list but the blank cells within range makes other problems for me.

Secondly I had this code and I tried to use it as Row Source for combobox but came out error.

```
Set Division = Worksheets("DataCMB").Range(Range("E2"), Range("E1048576").End(xlUp))
```

Please, help to find out the issue.

Comment: `Range("E2")` and `Range("E1048576")` are linked to the active sheet, not to `Worksheets("DataCMB")`

Comment: in `Set Division = ...`, `Division` is not a named range, it is a [Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel) variable.

Comment: If you want to modify a named range in vba, look for the [Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/names-object-excel) collection

Answer (score 1):

You can insert your A2:A61 as table and define as "Division" name. So when you add new data, new data will auto include into "Division"name.

Comment: If want to use vba try change to                                                   
    Division=Worksheets("DataCMB").Range(Range("E2"), Range("E1048576").End(xlUp)).address

Comment: Thanks for answer. But when I used table as you said I got debug message.

Comment: Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
          Division = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Address
          Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = Division
        End Sub

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have, and some of the other answers here have, is that you are not telling your 2nd and 3rd Range calls which sheet they should reference, so in the line below you can see I have added Worksheets("DataCMB") in front of them. Without that it will use the ActiveSheet which may not be set to DataCMB, so it will be looking for a range that is on a different sheet, and not find it.

The other problem was that your .End(xlUp) was working from a single cell and not a range, so I have changed it to look at the whole column and to look down instead of up. So the line below will give you the whole range of whatever is in that column, but will not include any blanks at the bottom, nor the header.

```
Set Division = Worksheets("DataCMB").Range(Worksheets("DataCMB").Range("E2"), Worksheets("DataCMB").Range("E2:E1048576").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: Daniel, Thanks. These advises fixed error happening when I stand on not DataCMB sheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Division = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Address
  Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = Division
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using code similar to this? I not facing error with the code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can insert table to your data and define name as "Division". It will auto include new data into your "Division" name.